# App not listed under "My Apps" when tagged as a Developer

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been added as a Developer to a LinkedIn app that's administered by someone else. However, I don't see it listed under "My Apps" in the LinkedIn Developers site. Where can I go to find it (so I can get API key information etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only Administrators have access to LinkedIn applications via "My Apps", not "Developers".  Members associated as a developer just benefit from increased call counts for dev/testing with, but cannot make changes to an app's configuration.

Get your administrator to add you as an admin, or to retrieve the info you require if they won't give you that level of permission.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Seems like it would be sensible for developers to at least be able to see the app information (even if in read-only), but hey!